# Is flower falling from photo towards left side a bad omen?

Tags: prayer, superstitions, omens

Today when I was praying to God, I saw flower which was tucked to the left side of the photo (Lakshmi-venkateshwara) fell down. Is it a good or bad omen, if it is falling towards left side?

Comment: Do you want to know falling of flower in general or falling towards left side?

Comment: @The Destroyer Both in fact. I want to know about both.

Comment: Its actually flower falling down.. left or right is immaterial here..coz it depends on which side of the idol u tucked the flower to start with..i think its a good sign..

Comment: Falling while you doing Puja is anugraham of God (even if lizard behind the photo pushes the flower). But if you put it in such as way that flower can fall, it is not grace of God.

Comment: When you have added the superstitions tag, why to ask whether it is good or bad? It is neither good nor bad. Concentrate on lord's prayer than these things. It is important than flower falling down.

Answer (score 3):

Flower falling while you pray itself is a good indication!  Flowers are always considered very sacred, Goddess Laxmi is shown sitting on a lotus and her Favorite flowers are Lotus and any kind of Red Flowers.

While worshipping If a flower falls from the Picture or idol its a Good sign that your wish is going to fulfil and you will get success in your works. Left and right both sides are equally beneficial, Though in some places right side is considered more auspicious than left!!

Though, there is nothing to worry about as it's overall a good sign! You should keep that flower with you.