# Cloth, flower along with Kalash falling from the altar during Ganesha Puja - is this a good or bad omen?

Tags: worship, prayer, omens

When I was worshiping Lord Ganesha I offered him cloth that is dhoti and flowers ..after I finished my aarti the cloths and flower just fell off which eventually led the Kalash to fall ..is this a bad omen or something good ?

Comment: Hi welcome to our site! The Kalasha getting dislodged might not be considered as a good sign but flowers etc falling off are often taken as signs of acceptance i.e such signs show that God is happy with ur Puja and he has accepted ur offerings.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to [Hinduism.se]. A similar kind of question was asked on our site. [Is flower falling from photo towards left side a bad omen?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18471/5212). Flower falling down doesn't mean it is a bad omen. We should just concentrate on the prayer. It is important than flowers falling down.

Comment: Falling flowers is generally considered as good sign, even if some lizard behind the photo was responsible for falling of flower.

Comment: @Rickross you can post answer, if scriptures or other sources don't talk about such things, then it looks opinion based.

Comment: I don't have any references to cite ..@Pandya